# Is there a fix? Transfered ggplot fails with "Error in coord$backtransform_range(panel_params)..."

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to transfer some ggplots from my work computer to my home computer. I saved the plots as an .Rdata-file with the standard `save` function. I loaded the object with the `load` function at home. I get the following error:

> "Error in coord$backtransform_range(panel_params) : 
>    attempt to apply non-function"

I have no problems making new ggplots without getting the error. Neither when I save these plots locally and load them again. I've also tried transferring the plots both through gmail and with my cell phone as a storage unit. Both computers use Windows 10 operating system.

I get the error when I run the following bit of code

```
library(tidyverse)
load("Object.Rdata")
object$main_plot
```

I did not expect that this would cause an error. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I suspect but am not entirely sure that there might be some inheritance problems in the `object$main_plot$coordinates`. When you were generating the plot, did you have a package loaded in that made changes to the `ggplot2::Coord` object or its children that you used?. When I transfer plots that I don't want to edit anymore, I usually save the output of `grob <- ggplotGrob(myplot)`, which converts it to a gtable and can be plotted by `grid.newpage();grid.draw(grob)` and seldomly run into problems.

Comment: I had the following packages loaded: `tidyverse`, `cprr`, `beepr`, `sqldf`, `compiler`,
`gridExtra`, `grid`. All in all pretty vanilla. Neither of them messes with ggplot to my knowledge (?). 
Thanks for the advice on saving plots with ggplotGrob. That is definitively noted for other projects. In this project though, I am actually interested in changing a couple of things, so this was not an option.

Comment: A thing you could try is adding `+ coord_cartesian()` (or other coordinates) to your plot, which should in theory override default coordinates and the `backtransform_range()` function. Another thing that you could check is wether the ggplot2 versions are the same on both computers.